Pandas, group by function and .mean()

Hello, I'm new with pandas. I am working with this data-frame and would like to get a table with the average precipitation for each month. I'm following an online course and they used the next line of code to do it:
seattle['month']=seattle['date'].dt.month
seattle['month_name']=seattle['date'].dt.month_name()
monthly_precip = seattle.groupby(['month', 'month_name']).mean()[['precipitation']].reset_index()
monthly_precip
In the course it worked well but, when I write it in my jupyter-notebook, it shows me the following error:

TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]

I tried to change the data type of the new column month from int32 to int64. That is the difference that I saw from the course but honestly I don't know why and also didn't work
seattle['month'].astype(np.int64)


Please [edit] your question and put there sample (small) input data and expected output as text (not as pictures, we cannot copy-paste them)

Please read [mre] and Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

perform indexing and then use mean function.:
monthly_precip = seattle.groupby(['month', 'month_name'])['precipitation'].mean().reset_index()

or pass numeric_only=True to mean in your code
monthly_precip = seattle.groupby(['month', 'month_name']).mean(numeric_only=True)[['precipitation']].reset_index()


instead of ".mean()"
monthly_precip = seattle.groupby(['month', 'month_name']).mean()[['precipitation']].reset_index()

try this:
mean(numeric_only = True)

https://community.dataquest.io/t/error-using-agg-fucntion-with-dataframe-groupby-agg-function-failed-how-mean-dtype-object/572703/4
